# Java parallelStream does not use expected number of threads

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8, java-stream

Java 8 parallelStream seems to use more threads than the ones specified by the system property **java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism**. These unit tests show that I process tasks using the desired number of threads using my own ForkJoinPool but when using parallelStream the number of threads is higher than expected.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class ParallelStreamTest {

    private static final int TOTAL_TASKS = 1000;

    @Test
    public void testParallelStreamWithParallelism1() throws InterruptedException {
        final Integer maxThreads = 1;
        System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism", maxThreads.toString());
        List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            objects.add(i);
        }

        final AtomicInteger concurrentThreads = new AtomicInteger(0);
        final AtomicInteger taskCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

        objects.parallelStream().forEach(i -> {
            processTask(concurrentThreads, maxThreads); //expected to be called one at the time
            taskCount.addAndGet(1);
        });

        assertTrue(taskCount.get() == TOTAL_TASKS);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMyOwnForkJoinPoolWithParallelism1() throws InterruptedException {
        final Integer threads = 1;
        List<Integer> objects = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_TASKS; i++) {
            objects.add(i);
        }

        ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(1);
        final AtomicInteger concurrentThreads = new AtomicInteger(0);
        final AtomicInteger taskCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

        forkJoinPool.submit(() -> objects.parallelStream().forEach(i -> {
            processTask(concurrentThreads, threads); //expected to be called one at the time
            taskCount.addAndGet(1);
        }));
        forkJoinPool.shutdown();
        forkJoinPool.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        assertTrue(taskCount.get() == TOTAL_TASKS);
    }

    /**
     * It simply processes a task increasing first the concurrentThreads count
     *
     * @param concurrentThreads Counter for threads processing tasks
     * @param maxThreads Maximum number of threads that are expected to be used for processing tasks
     */
    private void processTask(AtomicInteger concurrentThreads, int maxThreads) {
        int currentConcurrentThreads = concurrentThreads.addAndGet(1);
        if (currentConcurrentThreads > maxThreads) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("There should be no more than " + maxThreads + " concurrent thread(s) but found " + currentConcurrentThreads);
        }

        // actual processing would go here

        concurrentThreads.decrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

There should be only one thread used for processing tasks as the ForkJoinPool has `parallelism=1` and `java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1`. Therefore both tests should pass but **testParallelStreamWithParallelism1** fails with:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: There should be no more than 1 concurrent thread(s) but found 2

It seems that setting **java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1** is not working as expected and more than 1 concurrent task is processed simultaneously.

Any ideas?

Comment: @4castle Thanks for pointing it out, I have corrected testMyOwnForkJoinPoolWithParallelism1 to use parallelStream and it passes as expected while testParallelStreamWithParallelism1 fails

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parallelism setting of the Fork/Join pool determines the number of pool worker threads, but since the caller thread, e.g. the main thread, will work on the jobs too, there is always one more thread when using the common pool. That’s why the [default setting of the common pool is “number of cores minus one”](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.java#3431) to get an actual number of working threads equal to the number of cores.

With your custom Fork/Join pool, the caller thread of the stream operation is already a worker thread of the pool, hence, utilizing it for processing jobs doesn’t increase the actual number of working threads.

It must be emphasized that the interaction between the Stream implementation and the Fork/Join pool is entirely unspecified as the fact that streams use the Fork/Join framework under the hood is an implementation detail. There is no guaranty that changing the default pool’s properties has any effect on streams nor that calling stream operations from within a custom Fork/Join pool’s task will use that custom pool.

Answer (score 2):

Set this parameter as well:

```
    System.setProperty("java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.maximumSpares", "0");
```

This worked for me. Apparently (although not very well documented), there are allowed 'Spare' threads to pick up work from default ForkJoinPool.

Answer (score 1):

Run this example:

```
  IntStream.rangeClosed(0,9).parallel().forEach((i) -> {
      try {
        System.out.println("id - " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      } catch (Exception e) {
      }
    });
```

When you used parameter **java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism=1** you will see something like

```
id - main
id - main
id - ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
id - main
id - ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
id - main
id - ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
id - main
id - ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
id - ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1
```

As you now know streams use common ForkJoinPool(with paralelism=1) and in addition they use current thread also.

Answer (score 0):

You deleted the correct answer from your first posting of this question, so I'll expound and expand on it. Your problem is here:
`int currentConcurrentThreads = concurrentThreads.addAndGet(1);`
and here:

```
objects.parallelStream().forEach(i -> {
  processTask(concurrentThreads, maxThreads); //expected to be called one at the time
  taskCount.addAndGet(1);
});
```

Each thread in the parallel stream invokes `processTask`. Each therefore increments `concurrentThreads` (but for some reason not with 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html#incrementAndGet--
). Since each runs in parallel, they're all incrementing `concurrentThreads` before any can decrement it. So of course you exceed the number of threads you expect.

Comment: Your question says, "`testParallelStreamWithParallelism1` fails" but your comment says, "`testParallelStreamWithParallelism1` ... passes as expected". Which is it?

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question of how the parallel stream managed to use multiple threads in the first place.

Comment: There should be only 1 thread processing a task at the time as java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.parallelism is set to 1. This is what seems not to be working as expected. If only one thread processes a task at the time the test would pass as it occurs with testMyOwnForkJoinPoolWithParallelism1 which passes as expected.

Comment: Near as I can figure, you set the system property for the fork/join pool size too late. I'm still researching but the only documentation I found for setting the lambda fork/join pool size is a `-D` option to the java executable. I hypothesize that the size is set on JVM startup so that your setting of the property is ignored for the static pool that lambdas use.

Comment: @Lew Bloch: you can verify whether setting the option was too late via `System.out.println(ForkJoinPool.commonPool().getParallelism());` afterwards. If it prints the desired number, it was not too late (or happened to match the default).